# Xephyr - no gpu acceleration?

Tags: xorg, xephyr

I am making heavy use of Xephyr for x11 isolation. However,acceleration does not work at all.

3d programs simply do not run, video decoding does not work, vdpau does not work, things like chromium and other things bloatd with gpu using web crap are unusably slow.

I am using it like this.

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 800x600 :1
DISPLAY=:1 icewm
```

What is the issue? It's the same for when I set it up with doas or sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Xephyr is a basic, framebuffer-based implementation of an X server; it doesn’t support any form of 3D or video acceleration.

I’m not sure there’s any nested X server implementation which will provide better performance.

Answer (score 2):

[@stephen-kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) is right, Xephyr does not provide this natively. However, you can use [virtualGL](https://rawcdn.githack.com/VirtualGL/virtualgl/3.1/doc/index.html) for acceleration.
Download the 32-bit version for 32-bit applications and the other way around. I got it from [here], but you can also build it from source.

After this, you can use `Xephyr` to start a nested Xserver and `vglrun` to start the application.

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 800x600 :1
DISPLAY=:1 vglrun icewm
```